# Does a service worker allow one to simply use long expiration headers on static assets?

Tags: service-worker

Say I have a service worker that populates the cache with the following working code when its activated:

```
async function install() {
    console.debug("SW: Installing ...");
    const cache = await caches.open(CACHE_VERSION);
    await cache.addAll(CACHE_ASSETS);
    console.log("SW: Installed");
}
async function handleInstall(event) {
    event.waitUntil(install());
}
self.addEventListener("install", handleInstall);
```

When performs `cache.addAll()`, will the browser use its own internal cache, or will it always download the content from the site? This is important, because it one creates a new service worker release, and there are new static assets, the old version maybe be cached by the service worker.

If not then I guess one still has to do named hashed/versioned static assets. Something I was hoping service workers would make none applicable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`cache.addAll()`](https://w3c.github.io/ServiceWorker/#cache-addAll)'s behavior is described in the service worker specification, but here's a more concise summary:

1. For each item in the parameter array, if it's a string and not a `Request`, construct a new `Request` using that string as input.
2. Perform `fetch()` on each request and get a response.
3. As long as the response has an [`ok` status](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#ok-status), call `cache.put()` to add the response to the cache, using the request as the key.

To answer your question, the most relevant step is 1., as that determines what kind of `Request` is passed to `fetch()`. If you just pass in a string, then there are a [lot of defaults that will be used](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#request-class) when implicitly constructing the `Request`.  If you want more control over what's `fetch()`ed, then you should explicitly create a `Request` yourself and pass that to `cache.addAll()` instead of passing in strings.

For instance, this is how you'd explicitly set the [cache mode](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-request-cache-mode) on all the requests to `'reload'`, which always skip the browser's normal HTTP cache and go against the network for a response:

```
// Define your list of URLs somewhere...
const URLS = ['/one.css', '/two.js', '/three.js', '...'];

// Later...
const requests = URLS.map((url) => new Request(url, {cache: 'reload'}));
await cache.addAll(requests);
```

Comment: Wow thank you Jeff! I have read so many of your answers on SO before, and seen your name mentioned in Service worker outbreak (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CPP9ew4Co0M).